# Do my arms feel pain if I put them upwards in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, biology

On Earth, our arms feel pain if we put them upwards due to the gravitational force downwards. Is this also true when I find myself in empty space (without gravitation)?

Comment: I think you should see a doctor

Comment: maybe you do not feel pain, but a force? Pain ist when your hands are hurting. Usually that does not happen , if you put your hands upwards. without gravity you still have to move your hands, which needs some force, but much less than with gravity

Comment: Are you asking if you can physically feel the sensation of your arms moving *as you raise them over your head* Or are you asking if you can physically feel your arms exerting effort to resist some force once they are over your head? If the former, then I would assume you can feel yourself move your arms up. If the latter, there are no forces to resist, but you should still have a sensation that your limbs exist

Answer (score 1):

You might take way longer to feel pain and that pain you feel would be due to the tension in your arms muscles starting from your shoulders since they apply an internal potential force to keep your arms above your head level. Regardless of the gravity force, the body has its internal forces when it's inaction that the laws of Newtown still take place but on a biological scale.